# Escaping emoji characters

Tags: c#, twitter, escaping, emoji

I am trying to post a tweet with emoji characters but when I try to escape them I get a 401 error. I tried using `Uri.EscapeDataString` and then `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`. I even tried this:

```
string escapedStr = "";
foreach (char ch in emoji)
    escapedStr += Uri.HexEscape(ch);
```

Is there a special way of escaping them?

Comment: Can you give an example emoji and what its escaped string looks like?

Comment: Here's one "" and it's escaped string "%F0%9F%98%81".

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
    string escapedStr = "";
    string emoji = "";
    Console.WriteLine(Uri.EscapeDataString(emoji)); //Prints %F0%9F%98%81
```

You are trying to get the individual characters? like: %F ?